# No route matches [POST] "/profile/12/edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to make a custom edit form for devise user, but when I submit the form shell throw me this error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/profile/12/edit"
```

Here is my form:

```
= simple_form_for(:user), html: { method: :put }) do |f|
= f.input :email
= f.input :username
= f.input :phone
= f.input :password, autocomplete: "off", required: false
= f.input :password_confirmation, required: false
= f.input :current_password, required: true
= f.button :submit, 'Update'
```

Here is my profile_controller

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

And my routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'home#index'

  devise_for :users
  resources :profile

end
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried ```rake routes``` to see you available routes?

Comment: Actually if you submit user form then it will submitted to users_controller action, in your case you need to define url in your form

Comment: hmm, this means that if I build form for :user - this form was build for `users_controller` and not for my object `@user` from `edit` action?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
= simple_form_for(:user), html: { method: :put }) do |f|
```

with:

```
= simple_form_for @user, method: :put, url: "/profile" do |f|
```

Some of the mistakes:

- if you want to edit an object, provide it, not a mere symbol
- the path must be adjusted to point to `/profile`
- method not an html property, it creates a hidden field intercepted by rails in order to know the received `post` should be understood as a `put`
- we feel like there is a typo: controller should be pluralized

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
= simple_form_for @user, 
    :url => url_for(:action => 'edit', :controller => 'profiles'),
    :method => 'put' do |f|
```

Here you are submitting a PUT (update) request to the edit action of your `ProfilesController`.

Also notice the difference here between `ProfileController` and what I wrote `ProfilesController`. The convention in Rails and as for DHH is that your model names should be singular and your controller plural.

**model**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**controller**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
end
```

Comment: `update` is not reached using `POST` - you misspelled `profiles`

Comment: Woops. and no, the convention is that controller names should be pluralized and model singular

Comment: you can state all conventions but check what the OP wrote :)